# Does both Heap and Stack of Java reside in RAM, similar to C++?

Tags: java, heap-memory, ram, stack-memory

This question is not about difference between Stack and Heap in Java. 
In C++, both Stack and Heap are in RAM. 
How is it in Java?

Comment: you might like this article https://stackify.com/java-heap-vs-stack/

Comment: Just to be clear about the question : if not in RAM, where would it be (or said otherwise when you say "are in RAM", you mean as opposed to where ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes. Stack is used for static memory allocation and Heap for dynamic memory allocation, both stored in the computer's RAM

This is to ensure faster processing of java programs.

Comment: Any source for much more details. I'm more curious now.

Answer (score 1):

A process is a program in execution. It consists of data(stores global variables), heap(dynamic memory allocation), stack(function calls, local variables) and text part(this represents your code file). So I don't know much about Java, but I believe that irrespective of the programming language, stack and heap are to be available in primary memory only.

Comment: What is a primary memory?

Comment: RAM(Random Access Memory)

Answer (score -1):

This may help. 
https://medium.com/fhinkel/confused-about-stack-and-heap-2cf3e6adb771

In Java or C#, value types (primitives) are stored on the stack, reference types on the heap